# Windows 11 - System Settings -> Apps & Features -> Missing uninstall option

Tags: windows-11, uninstall

I updated Windows 10 to Windows 11 and everything is working great except 1 thing. I can't uninstall any app from Settings -> Apps -> Apps & Features, because three dots near application name is missing. (see included screenshot).

I tried sfc /scannow, looked into event logs, but nothing important here. Any tips how to solve this without reinstalling Windows?

[Image of Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUtby.png)

Comment: If you go to the control panel and go to add/remove programs are you able to uninstall the application(s) or if you reinstall the application(s) does the option to uninstall the application show up? The user is an Administrator? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Also, does Uninstall appear/work from the program list in the start menu (right-click on the app in the list/results in the start menu and select Uninstall)?

Comment: Work-around if you cannot get add/remove apps to work: try a third party tool, such as free Bulk Crap Uninstaller, https://www.bcuninstaller.com/ , or the many alternatives, https://alternativeto.net/software/bulk-crap-uninstaller/

Comment: I left steps for a Repair Install and followup from that to help you.

Comment: Yes, uninstalling from old control panel and start menu still works. Seems like its some bug in new settings app. I will probably wait for windows 22h2 update and see if its fixed.

Comment: I don’t think it is a bug in the Settings App. My Windows 11 systems work fine. Another Windows 11 machine (Insider) which has future feature updates shows no difference in thie Settings App

Comment: go to run menu and type: appwiz.cpl

Comment: Can you uninstall those items by right clicking them through there?

Comment: @Mastaxx, he already said _Yes, uninstalling from old control panel and start menu still works_.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade may not have worked perfectly. A good approach in this case is to run a Windows 11 Repair Install

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything. Start with this and see if this works.

If Keep Everything does not work, then back up and install Windows 11 fresh.

Comment: No; This approach is complete overkill; Windows has simply lost, “how”, to uninstall those applications. If that’s the case, and I am willing to almost guarantee that’s the case, then reinstalling Windows won’t solve anything.

Comment: My comment explains what I feel is an overkill approach, windows keeps track of how to uninstall software, provided it’s told how to do so in the first place. Attempting to provide feedback instead of immediately downvoting (since I don’t find the advice relevant to the problem that’s described), hopefully, the answer is improved instead of deleted.

Comment: I know that will happen so my feedback will remain, I forget who indicated I was abusing the voting system, but i heard that feedback (even though I strongly disagreed with it). Cannot find the deleted answer, associated with that comment, so recall who said it.

Comment: @Ramhound it may or may not be an overkill, but if Control Panel and Start Menu uninstalling works then it can't be Windows "lost how to uninstall"